# Displaying Labels on Stacked Bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, bar-chart, stacked-area-chart

I would like to display labels on each stacked bar like blue on blue bar, yellow on yellow bar and so on.
Here's my code in JSFiddle:

```
 [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Sa_2019/n7r57pv7/
```

Here is my Code :

```
 <div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
  var data = [
    {label: 'foo', color:'red', data: [[1,300], [2,300], [3,300], [4,300], [5,300]]},
    {label: 'bar', color:'blue', data: [[1,800], [2,600], [3,400], [4,200], [5,0]]},
    {label: 'baz', color:'yellow', data: [[1,100], [2,200], [3,300], [4,400], [5,500]]},
     ];

        $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, {
       series: {
       stack: 1,
       bars: {
        show: true,
        lineWidth: 1,
        barWidth: 0.8,
        order: 1, 
        fill: true
    },
    yaxis : {
        min : 0,
        tickLength: 0
    } ,
    xaxis: {
    tickLength: 0,
    axisLabel: "Date",
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
    axisLabelFontFamily: 'Arial',
    axisLabelPadding: 3,
    color: "#838383",
    timeformat: "%b/%y"
     }
    }
   });
```

Any idea please.

Thank you

Comment: Please put the (minimal) code needed to explain your question in the question itself.

Comment: fiddle not working ??

Comment: @AlokBhat http://jsfiddle.net/Sa_2019/n7r57pv7/

Comment: @AdrianHHH I added my code. I would like to show labels of each series

Comment: @AlokBhat I edited my Question and I added my code. I would like to show labels of each series for examples on blue series it has a label with text "Blue" and so on.

Comment: @AlokBhat 
I'm trying to display the customized label on each series of bar chart. No idea on how to do this.. Please help me. Label should be displayed inside each bar

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataLabels of Highcharts to solve this . the code will be like :-

```
   plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                  dataLabels: {
                     enabled: true,
                     color: 'white', 
                          formatter: function () {
                                  //  return the value you want to show on labels.. depends on your data ...
                           console.log(this)
                          }
                  }
            }
   }
```

something like this you can refer to ...
As of know i have added string "random" to it just change that according to your logic ..

http://jsfiddle.net/n1mcs4d1/

Comment: Is it possible to do it with flot Stacked Bar cause I am using flot.

Comment: I did some change on my code and still not working could you have a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/Sa_2019/e98q581L/1/

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about float .. so can't help .. though i found this  http://jsfiddle.net/1a2s35m2/1/

Comment: You see the example on JSFiddle the one with High Charts, I can see all the labels have same text "random" How do you change the text for Blue series and change the text again for yellow series ? Any idea please.